# "by" or "through"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Let's say I want to tell a person to imagine a 3D object and then build the object using his hands.

How do I say the same in a three word tagline like a company tagline?

Should I say “Build by Imagination”

or “Build through Imagination”

or something else?

Comment: You do not need an adjunct/adverbial phrase or "in his mind" - the mind is the only place you can "imagine" anything.: *Imagine a 3D object  and then build it.*

Comment: @Greybeard corrected.

Comment: You do not need "by/through imagination" either. As I said: *Imagine a 3D object and then build it.* (or do you mean he should build it "***in* their imagination**"

Comment: @Greybeard I want a three word tagline like a company tagline. Like GE's "Imagination at work" Or Audi's "Advancement at work".

Comment: My apologies - I misread the question. "Build by Imagination" is fine.

Comment: I would maybe say "build it in your mind" or "imagine building it in your mind".  But more likely would be "envision the process of building it".